# Faster way to do individual inserts?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which deals with adding nodes in a tree. Basically the table structure is

```
id INT PRIMARY
label VARCHAR(1) /* the value of the node which is a character */
parent_id INT /* id of the parent node */
```

Here is my stored procedure:

```
/* 
    takes a word, and adds every character in to the table 
    where every character is a child of the previous character
    the first character of every word is a child of the root
*/
CREATE PROCEDURE rule(IN word VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    /* (parent_id = 0) => child of root */
    DECLARE pid INT DEFAULT 0; /* parent id */
    DECLARE npid INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE strlength INT;
    DECLARE j INT DEFAULT 1; 
    DECLARE query_count INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE active_char VARCHAR(1);
    SET strlength = LENGTH(word);
    /* loop through the word */
    WHILE j <= strlength DO
        /* get a single character from word */
        SET active_char = SUBSTR(word,j,1);
        /* if the character doesn't already exist, insert it */
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO query_count FROM tree
        WHERE parent_id = pid AND label = active_char;
        IF (query_count = 0) THEN
            INSERT INTO tree (label, parent_id)
            VALUES (active_char,pid);
        END IF;
        /* Set the new parent id */
        SELECT id INTO npid FROM tree
        WHERE label = active_char AND parent_id = pid;
        SET pid = npid;
        SET j = j + 1;
    END WHILE;
END //
```

I'm sure there are a few tweaks I can make to make the procedure a bit more efficient but I can't think of anything that would significantly reduce the time needed.

I'm dealing with a lot of words which means this procedure is run a couple 100,000 times which in turn means a lot of inserts and a lot of queries. It takes hours perhaps days(not sure because I gave up waiting and stopped the process).

The thing is, I don't think I can do a bulk insert because every insert depends on a previous insert.

I was wondering if there's some way to create a virtual table that's stored in main memory to do all these operations fast and then just save the result in to the actual table.

At the moment, the only possible solution I can think of is to build the tree in PHP and then do a bulk insert. I think this should be faster but I'm not sure up to what degree.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This will probably be way faster outside of the database, since it won't need to worry about IO and consistency.

Comment: Whats your table like that you are inserting into?  any indexes?  Primary key?

Comment: The table has 3 fields. Id, label and parent_id with id being the primary key. No indexes.

Comment: using last_insert_id() should eliminate the last query. 
Why are you checking if a character you've not inserted already exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst I'm afraid I can't claim to have used it myself, passing the data down to the stored procedure as XML and processing it as [described here](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/xml-in-mysql5.1-6.0.html#xml-5.1-importing) would seem a reasonable approach.  N.B.  MySQL 5.1 or higher.

Comment: Ideally the xml would have the structure of the tree, i.e. A child node would be a child element within the xml, then that would be quite fast to process because I wont have to loop through 1000s of elements to find and id. I dont think thers any I can get this format from the database so if I do use xml I might just consider using it instead of the database altogether

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts:

1. "Reducing the time" means you have to show us the schema, indexes, queries, and `EXPLAIN` (each of the statements in the procedure).
2. Use `INSERT IGNORE` instead of the `SELECT/INSERT` pair that you're using now.
3. You don't need to `SELECT` the ID back out - use `LAST_INSERT_ID()`
4. Why select into npid and then copy into pid?  Just select into pid.

Comment: @1 I'm not sure what more information I can give.
@2 How does using INSERT IGNORE replace the SELECT statement?
@3 Yeh that's probably a better idea. Thanks.
@4 When I first ran the procedure I had a bug and I thought that statement was causing it. I thought perhaps you can insert into a variable which you are also using to query. I forgot to change it back.